# using datetimepicker.js to select the needed .js file

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

could you please help me with the following problem : 
I have a datetimepicker.js file that creates a calendar, where the user can select both date(day/month/year) and the time(HH/MM). 
I have a collection of .js file in folders (for example Kiel-Berlin folder contains files: KiBe04.js, KiBe05.js,KiBe06.js,...). I want the calendar to work such a way that if a user selects e.g. date 21march2014 and sets hours as 04:00 then the script would select the file KiBe04, if user selects 05:00 the selected file would be KiBe05, etc. An each file KiBe04,KiBe05, contains a variable array(e.g KiBe04 = [1,2,3,4,5], KiBe05=[6,7,8,9] ...) that needs to be selected for processing once the user selects the date and time(appropriate hour). Datetimepicker.js downloaded by http://www.rainforestnet.com is in the [hyperlink.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml)

Thanx for your help, highly appreciate !

Comment: If you only have one variable in the file anyhow, why don't you just list them as an object (`var allVariables = {"KiBe05": [1,2,3,4,5]}`) and select them like that (`var myThing = allVariables["KiBe05"];`) instead of loading external files? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I have multiple variables (KiBe04,....KiBe10, BaShe04....BaShe10), each of them are arrays to contain different values(not sequential actually).I want datetimepicker cal.to help user to chose the file(thereby the contained array name) through setting date and time.E.g. users selection of 21march2014 and time 0400am would select KiBe04.js file and the containing KiBe04 = [.....] array.I dont know what value in datetimepicker stores the selected hours, mins, year as string.

Comment: How does a date of, say `March 21st 2015 at 16:00` translate into `KiBe10` (or similar) anyhow? Do you want timezone abbreviation + hour with two digits? If you could tell us what you want to construct, we might be able to help. If you need the timezone names you'll have to construct (or find) those yourself and connect them to the values of `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`. In that case, you should look into the javascript `Date` object and structure your files around what you can do there. And again, including one file with a list of arrays is easier than important thousands of js files.

Answer (score 0):

First change date picker if you can. It's really outdated. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ looks sane but I never tried . Then add:

```
jQuery('your element').on('change.dp',function(data){
   var fileName = data// prepare data to get proper name of script. 
   jQuery.getScript(basePath+fileName,function(){
        //execute after getting the script
   });
})
```

Why not this date picker? It have really old API and bad documentation. I cannot seem to find any way to add any observer to the date picker and that's what you need.